# Using Maps for Validation

Tags: c++

I have this code that is meant to work as a quiz. It randomly lists a State and you must type in the Capital of said state and it has to be case sensitive. The whole program runs with absolutely no errors. However, no matter what I enter as the capital, the program marks it as incorrect. Am I programming the validation wrong? I tried re-doing the function with different variables but I still get the same error. The program uses vectors and maps in order to list the states and match them with the appropriate capital.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int randomfunction(int i)
{
    int ran = (rand() % i) + 1;
    return ran;
}

int number;
int rightans = 0;
int wrongans = 0;
string userinput = "1";
string teststate;
string testcapital;
string useranswer;
string captialans;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is my Capital Quiz. This program is CASE SENSITIVE." << endl;
    cout << "Creating States..." << endl;
    vector<string> teststates{ "Georgia", "Alabama", "Florida", "New Mexico", "New Jersey", "New Hempshire",
        "Washington", "California", "Oregon", "Mississipi", "Tennesse", "North Carolina", "Nebraska",
        "South Carolina", "Maine", "Vermont", "Maryland", "Missouri", "Nevada", "New York", "Arkansas", "Idaho",
        "West Virginia", "South Dakota", "Indiana", "Delaware", "Kentucky", "Colorado", "Texas", "Massachusetts", "Oregon",
        "North Dakota", "Minnesota", "Michigan", "Louisiana", "Wisconsin", "Utah", "Nebraska", "Oklahoma", "Rhode Island",
        "Arizona", "Pennsylvania", "Connecticut", "Ohio", "Wyoming", "Hawaii", "Virginia", "Illinois", "Montana", "Kansas", "Iowa"};
    cout << "Creating Map..." << endl;
    map <string, string> testcapitals =
    {
        {"Georgia","Atlanta"}, {"Alabama","Montgomery"}, {"Florida","Tallahassee"}, {"New Mexico","Santa Fe"}, {"New Jersey","Trenton"},
        {"New Hempshire","Concord"}, {"Washington","Olympia"}, {"California","Sacramento"}, {"Oregon","Salem"}, {"Mississipi","Jackson"},
        {"Tennesse","Nashville"}, {"North Carolina","Raleigh"}, {"Nebraska","Lincoln"}, {"South Carolina","Columbia"}, {"Maine","Augusta"},
        {"Vermont","Montpelier"}, {"Maryland","Annapolis"}, {"Missouri","Jefferson City"}, {"Nevada","Carson City"}, {"New York","Albany"},
        {"Arkansas","Little Rock"}, {"Idaho","Boise"}, {"West Virginia","Charleston"}, {"South Dakota","Pierre"}, {"Indiana","Indianapolis"},
        {"Delaware","Dover"}, {"Kentucky","Frankfort"}, {"Colorado","Denver"}, {"Texas","Austin"}, {"Massachusetts","Boston"},
        {"Oregon","Salem"}, {"North Dakota","Bismarck"}, {"Minnesota","St. Paul"}, {"Michigan","Lansing"}, {"Loisiana","Baton Rouge"},
        {"Wisconsin","Madison"}, {"Utah","Salt Lake City"}, {"Nebraska","Lincoln"}, {"Oklahoma","Oklaholma City"}, {"Rhode Island","Providence"},
        {"Arizona","Phoenix"}, {"Pennsylvania","Harrisburg"}, {"Connecticut","Hartford"}, {"Ohio","Columbus"}, {"Wyoming","Cheyenne"},
        {"Hawaii","Honolulu"}, {"Virginia","Richmond"}, {"Illinois","Springfield"}, {"Montana","Helena"}, {"Kansas","Topeka"}, {"Iowa","Des Moines"},
    };

    while (userinput == "1")
    {
        number = randomfunction(50);
        teststate = teststates[number - 1];
        testcapital = testcapitals[teststate];
        cout << "Please type in the capital of " << teststate << ". Please Enter it as case sensitive." << endl;
        getline(cin, useranswer);
        if (useranswer == captialans)
        {
            cout << "That Answer is correct. Good Job." << endl;
            rightans++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "That answer is incorrect. Study up." << endl;
            wrongans++;
        }
        cout << "Press 1 to do another question, or 0 to get your results and end." << endl;
        getline(cin, userinput);
    }

}
```

It's probably a simple fix but I'm still kind of struggling with this language so any help would be appreciated. I'm also completely new to vectors and mapping.

Comment: tip: declare variables only when you can initialize them, this avoids this and many other errors

Comment: not the problem, but you dont need the vector of states and the map. The map already has all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think this line of code does?

```
if (useranswer == captialans)
```

`captialans` is a variable which you declare but which your never give a value to (in fact this is the only place in the whole program that you use this variable). Because `captialans` is never given a value it's value defaults to the empty string. So this code checks if the user has entered an empty string.

Here's the correct code

```
if (useranswer == testcapital)
```

`testcaptial` is the variable with the corrrect answer that you've looked up in the map. You did that on this line of code

```
testcapital = testcapitals[teststate];
```

Comment: thank you, that was a careless mistake. I did rework it into a validation function to check to see if no answer was created though. Thank you!